# How to make Android activities smaller with better OO

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I often come across a problem with my activities turning into large sprawling classes that are difficult to read and maintain. For example if i have a search form activity there is a lot going on. Some of the fields are populated with data from a web service call, some of the fields respond to actions on the other fields, saving state, restoring state, handling user input etc.

As I see it there are a few options to improve this:

1. Split the activity into several fragments with each fragment controlling a group of related fields. This approach has several advantages. The fragments can be easily re-used in other activities e.g. if you have a basic search activity and an advanced search activity the basic search fragment could be re-used in the advanced search activity. You also get the life cycle hooks, so the fragment can be responsible for saving and restoring it's own state as well as pausing and restarting server calls etc. A disadvantage of this approach is the fact that you can't have fragments within fragments. So say for instance if you wanted to use a fragment view pager you couldn't nest these smaller fragments in a larger container fragment to go in the view pager. Also I'm not sure if this fits in with design philosophy of fragments. If you read the android dev docs on fragments it seems to imply that a fragment should be equivalent to an activity on a phone, it's only when it comes to larger devices that you would have multiple fragments on the screen.
2. Implement custom view groups that control a group of related fields. Again this will have the advantage removing a lot of the code relating to those fields from the activity and you will end up with a re-usable UI component. It is also has the ability to save and restore it's own state. A disadvantage of this would be that it will still be tied to the activity to control lifecycle events. Also I'm not sure if it is appropriate for these custom view groups to retrieve their own data from a web service or database call, handle user input etc. To me a custom view group should only be responsible for displaying data on the UI.
3. Implement a bespoke MVC type framework where the activity grabs the views out of the layout and creates a collection of POJO controllers that are responsible for populating the fields, performing web service and database calls and handling user input. Again a disadvantage of this approach is the activity will still be responsible for propagating life cycle events in order for the controllers to save and restore state etc.

I'm very interested in how other people approach and solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I think one common approach would be for everyone try his or her best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I plan on using parts of the UI for phone and tablet I like to use Fragments to group those responsibilities. Since the release of Android 4.2 Fragments have the method [getChildFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) this allows nested fragments and this method is also available through the support library.

For all other cases I create POJO controllers that are created with the ViewGroup they handle.
If they need special call backs from the Activity you have to deliver this methods to the controller. This is sometimes tiresome but still cleaner then having all the code in the activity lifecycle callback method.